# The markdown preview shows wrong formatting whereas the Markdown shows it right

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

The question formatting when edited using markdown(editor) shows it correctly in the editor but wrongly in the markdown preview. But then again appears correctly in the question. Reference question : [Adding multiple rows with common Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055747/adding-multiple-rows-with-common-name)

Actually in question :

[image]

In question edit screen(Markdown):

[image]

In the preview section of the markdown:

[image]

Why is the Markdown preview showing it wrong?

Comment: Tabs instead of spaces, tsk, tsk, tsk.

Comment: Does that matter? Spaces rendered differently in the markdown preview?

Comment: @AniMenon The markdown input itself contains tabs. They are rendered as spaces, and apparently don't align as intended in the preview. Tabs are not meant for this.

Comment: @Stijn that is alright, but my query is shouldn't the preview be same as the markdown output?